# Creating image folders in IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, objective-c++

All,

When the user of my app takes a photo, it will be saved but i want it to save in a new folder called 'Jasons Photos' and not the usual Camera Roll album.

I know of the completion block called `save image:image` toAlbum 'Jasons Album' with `completion block`, but I get an error complaining that '`No visible @interface for AlAssetslibrary declares the selector 'save image to album completion block'` and its driving me crazy.

I have created an `@property for the ALAssets library` and i have included `<AssetsLibrary>` in my project.

thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this category: [https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum) I have used it in projects before. Taking a look at the implementation, the category created an asset group of a name you specify (if it doesn't already exist), tells the assets library to save to camera roll, gets the asset URL of the asset and saves the image at that URL to the newly created assets group. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You first need to write it to the savedPhotos, then get the ALAsset and add it to a new group

```
#import "QBViewController.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@implementation QBViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [lib writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"polter"] CGImage] orientation:ALAssetOrientationUp completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        if(assetURL) {
            [lib assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                [self addAsset:asset toGroup:@"forest" inLib:lib];
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"e: %@", error);
            }];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"e: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void) addAsset:(ALAsset*)a toGroup:(NSString*)name inLib:(ALAssetsLibrary*)lib {
    [lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:name]) {
            [group addAsset:a];
            *stop = YES;
            NSLog(@"added asset to EXISTING group");
        }
        if(!group) {
            [lib addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:name resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                [group addAsset:a];
                NSLog(@"added asset to NEW group");
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"e: %@", error);
            }];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"e: %@", error);
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: it does ;) assuming your image is named polter.png of course :D

Comment: sorry i missed that. only saw the addAssert in one place.

Comment: I am still getting the error : No visible @interface for add:asset to group. I have imported the AlAssetsLibrary from git hub, still no joy. what am I missing :)

Comment: you don't need to import stuff from github. and... there is no add:asset... there is only addAsset

Comment: I know this is old, but when adding the asset to a group/folder, does it move the asset or does the asset still show up in camera Roll as well?